# Cypress on WSL with X-Server opens empty windows

Tags: cypress, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I've followed [this article](https://shouv.medium.com/how-to-run-cypress-on-wsl2-989b83795fb6) for running Cypress on WSL (Ubuntu distribution).

When I run `cypress open` in WSL it does open Cypress app on Windows but Cypress doesn't display anything and WSL throws errors:

```
[4186:1214/162139.560525:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[4186:1214/162139.560902:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[4186:1214/162139.564644:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(63)] Failed to enable receiving udev events.
[4186:1214/162139.579120:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[4339:1214/162139.734198:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[4339:1214/162139.739939:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
```

When I run `cypress run` (headless) tests end with timeout:

```
Running:  layout/footer.spec.ts                                                          (1 of 19)
Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying...
```

When I run `cypress run --headed` it opens VcXsrv window but it's all empty:

[image]

After a while it opens another VcXsrv window, also empty. While tests are failing with timeouts (`The browser never connected. Something is wrong.`) it continues to open more and more empty VcXsrv windows.

My Node version is 16.1.8. Cypress version 9.7.0. Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS.